# Coloring 50% of the progress bar

Tags: html, css

I have to color **50%** of the progress bar with red color. Here is what I have tried , my css and html:

```css
.progress {
  width:100%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0.4615384615384615em;
  padding: 0.0769230769230769em;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0, #f2f2f2 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ffffff), color-stop(100%, #f2f2f2));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0, #f2f2f2 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0, #f2f2f2 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0, #f2f2f2 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0, #f2f2f2 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ffffff, endColorstr=#f2f2f2, GradientType=0);
  filter: none \9;
}
.progress.complete {
  height: 0.9em;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="id1" class="progress complete">
    <span title="" style="background: red; left: 0%; width: 50%; box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), inset 0px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);" rel="tooltip"></span>
</div>
```

How to color it without adding any text to `<span>` element in the output?

Comment: make the span block or inline-block - probably better with block so you don't get any space underneath

Comment: ... and set a height for it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgot to mention `height` & `position` to `span` tag

```css
.progress {
  width:100%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0.4615384615384615em;
  padding: 0.0769230769230769em;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0, #f2f2f2 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ffffff), color-stop(100%, #f2f2f2));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0, #f2f2f2 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0, #f2f2f2 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0, #f2f2f2 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0, #f2f2f2 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ffffff, endColorstr=#f2f2f2, GradientType=0);
  filter: none \9;
}
.progress.complete {
  height: 0.9em;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="id1" class="progress complete">
    <span title="" style="background: red; left: 0%; width: 50%; box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), inset 0px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);height: 100%; position: absolute;top: 0;" rel="tooltip"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do that without `span tag` then use `pseudo selector ::after` as below to style that,

```css
.progress {
  width:100%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0.4615384615384615em;
  padding: 0.0769230769230769em;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0, #f2f2f2 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ffffff), color-stop(100%, #f2f2f2));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0, #f2f2f2 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0, #f2f2f2 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0, #f2f2f2 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0, #f2f2f2 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ffffff, endColorstr=#f2f2f2, GradientType=0);
  filter: none \9;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.progress:after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  background: red; 
  left: 0%;
  top:0;
  width: 50%;
  height:10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), inset 0px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index:9;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="id1" class="progress complete">

</div>
```

`Span tag` `default` display is `inline` so you need to change that to `inline-block` and `height` to it.

```css
.progress {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0.4615384615384615em;
  padding: 0.0769230769230769em;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0, #f2f2f2 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ffffff), color-stop(100%, #f2f2f2));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0, #f2f2f2 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0, #f2f2f2 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0, #f2f2f2 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0, #f2f2f2 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ffffff, endColorstr=#f2f2f2, GradientType=0);
  filter: none \9;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.progress.complete {
  height: 0.9em;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  background: red;
  left: 0%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 15px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
   box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div id="id1" class="progress complete">
  <span title="progress bar" rel="tooltip"></span>
</div>
```